# Email Services - Add setReplyTo email while sending email from record detail page of an object

Tags: apex, lightning, email, lightning-experience, apex-email-service

I have created an email service and got an email address like
**email_handler@9w9wya19o......**

I want to capture the email response of email that I am sending from the record detail page but I am unable to set **setReplyTo** here. We cannot capture email response without adding setReplyTo. Can anyone please help with it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of Spring 19, I don't believe you can adjust `setReplyTo` on Lightning emails via the UI.  You can attempt to write a `before insert` trigger on the `EmailMessage` object and see if you can adjust the `replyTo` property within the trigger.

If the trigger approach doesn't work, I'd suggest having your users setup email forwarding on their email accounts to your email handler.  If you use G Suite, you can setup conditional forwarding, so that the forwarding filter logic could scan for a particular pattern that you use when emailing from the Lightning UI (like a standardized signature, etc), so that only relevant emails will be forwarded to your email handler

Comment: Thanks for your response, but replyTo email address field is missing on the EmailMessage object. So we can't use set replyTo by the trigger.

Comment: Didn't know that about the EmailMessage object, which is why I suggested the other approach as well.  Definitely much more work involved, but you could come up with a working process if you have time/budget for it